# How do I grab Contract Balance with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity

**Situation**

I have created a smart contract and imported the `abi` and contract address into my react application.

I have successfully accessed the methods and options within my react app. I used useEffect with no issues.

**Problem**

However, I am struggling to get the balance of the contract. I have tried everything I understand with no result.

**This code works fine**

```
import web3 from "./web";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Lottery from "./Lottery";

const [isManager, setManager] = useState(
        "<em>Loading manager address...</em>"
    );

    useEffect(() => {
    const getManager = async () => {
        const mangWallet = await Lottery.methods.manager().call();
        console.log(mangWallet);
        setManager(mangWallet);
    };

    getManager();
}, []);
```

**This does NOT work - the balance remains 0. More importantly, the console log doesn't even show 0. It's as if the entire `getBalance` function is not running?**

```
const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
        const getBalance = async () => {
            const contBal = await web3.eth.getBalance(Lottery.contract_address);
            setBalance(contBal);
            console.log(balance);
        };
        getBalance();
    }, []);
```

A few things to be aware of:

- `contract_address` is holding the smart contract address on-chain, stored in the Lottery.js file
- these two code snippets are in one file - `app.js`. Meaning there are two `useEffect` functions.

Comment: how did you create Lottery contract

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem. But I think this async `const contBal = await web3.eth.getBalance(Lottery.contract_address);` can throw exception. So I think you need to add try catch like this:

```
const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    const getBalance = async () => {
        try {
          const contBal = await web3.eth.getBalance(Lottery.contract_address);
          setBalance(contBal);
          console.log(balance);
        } catch(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    };
    getBalance();
}, []);
```

About the `console.log(balance)`, it alway log 0. Because it's behavior of `useEffect`. So you need to create another `useEffect` if you want to see the `balance` value change like this:

```
useEffect(() => { console.log(balance) }, [balance])
```

Comment: Why is it that I did not have to create another useEffect to see the `getManager` console log? console.log(mangWallet) works fine?

Comment: `console.log(mangWallet)` work, because you are log the response of the request
`console.log(balance)` not work, because you are log the state, it's not response from the request